# Диффузия в Matlab

Tags: matlab, физика

Я хочу смоделировать диффузию атомов примеси из одного кристаллита в другой. Коэффициент самодиффузии зависит от концентрации и температуры. Площадь их соприкосновения и температура в печи меняются во времени. Т.е. это не просто условия Неймана или Дирихле. Атомы допанта уходят из одного кристаллита, в результате чего скорость диффузии в нем меняется, приходят в другой и там коэффициент также меняется.

Я так понимаю c помощью Matlab PDE задача не решаема? Если да, то какую программу порекомендуете? Если нет, то где можно почитать или найти пример?

Comment: Пробую решить задачу через квазилинейные уравнения.